# Find "$g(x)$" knowing that "$x=\int_{0}^{\infty} g(tx) dt$"???

Tags: integration, integral-transforms

The entire question states what I am looking for. I'm looking for a function $g(x)$ in terms of $x$ which satisfies the condition that follows. This seems like it's related to "integral transformations," a topic I've seen before, but have never studied much. So, I don't even know where to begin trying to find $g(x)$. Thank you very much!

Comment: Try mutiply by $x$ and change variables $u = tx$. Is the equation you get sensible?

Comment: I'm confused, what is $x$? Does it hold for any $x$ or for one $x$?

Comment: @Soke It holds for any $x$

Comment: Ok I think I have my bearings better now.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{array}\\
x
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} g(tx) dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} g(y) dy/x
\qquad t\,x = y, t = y/x, dt = dy/x\\
\text{so}\\
x^2
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} g(y) dy\\
\end{array}
$

Looks like it holds
for only one
(or two) $x$.

Comment: Well that's a start, but what would I do afterwards?

Comment: I don't think there's anything else to do. This shows that there does not exist any such function $g$ that works for all $x$.

Comment: @JohnBarber Why though?

Comment: Because the expression $\int_0^{\infty} g(y) dy$ is independent of $x$. In fact, for any given function $g$ you might choose, this integral is just some number (assuming it converges). So what you have is $x^2$ = some number. That means that the last expression above can only be valid for at most two values of $x$,

Comment: @JohnBarber Oh that makes sense! Thanks for letting me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really really want a function, try this one: The domain contains only the point $x=0$, and $g(0)=0$.

Comment: How does this function makes sense? The integral is taken over $0 \to \infty$, so the domain of $g$ we need is $[0, \infty)$ at least.

Comment: Well, it you only allow the value of $x$ to be $0$ in the OP's equation, then only $g(0)$ need to be defined.

Comment: I agree that there is no solution if the equation holds for any $x$.

Comment: Oh gotcha yea you're right.